# How to install package html_to_etree using pip?

Tags: python, pip, package

I tried installing `html_to_etree` package in my virtual environment and it shows many errors. one of them is

> error: command '/usr/bin/clang++' failed with exit status 1

anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: Show us the full `pip` output.

Comment: Version 0.2 released in 2017 with the status *Pre-Alpha*. Seems the package is not yet ready and already abandoned.